# How can I know how long lasted the checkout?

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I'm configured a project to run nightly. After a while we switched the SVN server location and I want to know the differences in the time duration, including the checkout.

Is there a place to see it?

Comment: how did you configure the project to run nightly?  what operating system or automated build tool are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Run the checkout script/command with `time` in front of it.

E.g. do `time svn checkout` instead of your normal `svn checkout`.

Comment: It's useful to note this only works as expected under unix-like OSes. Under Windows, the time command does something rather different: it shows or sets the system time.

Answer (score 1):

That depends entirely on your environment. The SVN executable does not output any timing information by itself, but nothing stops you or your build environment from noting the start and end time of the process and calculating the difference. In MSBuild for example, you can specify the /v:diag switch to get very verbose output, including timing information for all the targets and tasks.